# Evenly space a bunch of <p> under each other, so that they auto size to fit a parent div

Tags: css

In my site, I have the parent container a_serv_detail, inside the cover div, now it's one thing to center one paragraph inside it, but I don't know how to have all the `<p>` one under another *inside* the container, with the container being a fixed sized, and the paragraphs evenly spaced.

```html
<img id='a_serv_img' src='a.png' style='position:absolute;z-index:1;width:50%;height:50%;left:0%;top:0%;'></img>
<div id='a_serv_cover' style='position:absolute;z-index:2;width:50%;height:50%;left:0%;top:0%;background-color:red;opacity:0.7;'>
  <p id='a_serv_p'>Power Purchase Agreement</p>
  <span id='a_serv_detail' style='visibility:hidden;font-size:18pt;width:50%;left:25%;top:50%'>
<p>•We install a solar system on your roof</p>
<p>•Zero capital required</p>
<p>•Free Maintenence</p>
<p>•Free insurance</p>
<p>•lorem ipsum</p>
<p>• lorem ipsum</p>
<br>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<br>
<p>•lorem ipsum</p>
</span>
</div>
```

[image: How is is now]

See I want what is here, but I want multiple paragraphs, one under the other,
but all the paragraphs together should be centered.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: please explain your problem in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that height of your parent is enough for your "p" tags then it' s pretty easy:

```
#a_serv_cover {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/a5ITabE

this happens then, but thanks for quick response

Comment: Seems like you do not have enough height for all these tags. Just for testing purposes, give it fixed height of 700px, so we can discard some of the causes.

Comment: Just tried that, /: can I link the whole file? it's a very short file

http://www.mediafire.com/file/0zkqn326ev12mfe/test.html/file

Comment: This is how I got https://ibb.co/t4J8Bzp If this is how it really is, then you first need to separate all your sentences to P tags, as you did in your question. And don' t wrap them in span. Use divs or something.

Comment: turns out I had a global 'position:absolute;' that broke it, but your code is still technically right so I'll give you an answer